# Laravel Jenssegers insert array values

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel with mongodb(Jenssegers), i have array data like following,

```
 $insert[] = ['sub_id'=>$loggedin,
              'userid' => $row->userid,
              'username' => $row->username,
              'email' => $row->email,
              'mobileno' => $row->mobileno,
              'manager_mail' => $row->manager_mail,
              'roleid' => $userrole->roleid];
```

my insert query is,

```
 $user->save($insert);
```

But its not working, please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `create()` or `insert()` methods:

```
User::create($insert);
```

Or:

```
User::insert($insert);
```

Or:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent [save](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) method accept `1D` array. But you provided `2D`. Please try following code:

```
 $insert = ['sub_id'=>$loggedin,
          'userid' => $row->userid,
          'username' => $row->username,
          'email' => $row->email,
          'mobileno' => $row->mobileno,
          'manager_mail' => $row->manager_mail,
          'roleid' => $userrole->roleid];

 $user->save($insert);
```